# Every NPM command is returning error after proxy is set for npm in MAC OS High Sierra

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, macos-sierra

I am not able to find .npmrc file anywhere on my system and as suggested in other threads I created my own .npmrc but doees'nt seems to work.

I am unable to run any command except: npm -v

Below is the error message returned in bash:

```
URIError: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at Url.parse (url.js:334:19)
at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:144:13)
at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:172:13)
at validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:221:24)
at validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:187:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:104:12
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:70:15
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61
  throw new Error('npm.load() required')
  ^

Error: npm.load() required
at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61:13)
at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:448:27)
```

Comment: Try cleaning the cache `npm cache clean --force`;

Comment: You can also do a dirty trick to see what is causing this problem, just do a `console.log()` in `Url.parse (url.js:334:19)` and run the same command with and without proxy.

Comment: npm cache clean --force returns same error @NeerajWadhwa

Comment: Where is that proxy set? And how did you set it?

Comment: I set it using command line,                                                                 
npm config set http-proxy http://A1xa57xj:VlVf%-5v@northproxy.airtelworld.in:4145

Comment: I think ` A1xa57xj:VlVf%-5v` part of the URL is causing this problem.

Comment: yes % causes the error but how to reset and get everything back to normal. I am unable to run any npm command except npm-v

Comment: Try URL encoding and decoding for this URL and use that as your proxy, if that doesn't work then try removing the proxy. Also, try escaping `%` part.

Comment: would you please elaborate steps

Comment: Try using `\%` instead of just `%`.